# React - Is it best for performance to use useEffect or change a value directly within the onChange method?

Tags: reactjs, select, react-hooks, onchange

If I have two select controls, one which is dependant on the other, so that if I change `selectA` value, `selectB` value will be selected depending on it:

```
...
const [values, setValues] = useState({ selectA: undefined, selectB: undefined });
const setSelectValue = (field, value) => {
  setValues((current) => {...current, [field]: value});
}

return (
  <>
    <Select
      name="selectA"
      value={values.selectA}
      onChange={(val) => setSelectValue('selectA', val)}
      ...
    />
    <Select
      name="selectB"
      value={values.selectB}
      onChange={(val) => setSelectValue('selectB', val)}
      ...
    />
  </>
);
```

In terms of performance, would it be best to use `useEffect` or just change the `selectB` value on the `selectA` `onChange` method?

```
// Is it best to use useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  setSelectValue('selectB', values.selectA.potato);
}, [values.selectA]);

// ... or is it best to change it directly on onChange method?
<Select
  name="selectA"
  value={values.selectA}
  onChange={(val) => {
    setSelectValue('selectA', val);
    setSelectValue('selectB', val.potato);
  }}
  ...
/>
```

**Does it matter at all? Is there any difference in terms of performance between both?**

I understand that `useEffect` can come handy for side effects that depend on data that can be updated at any time, but in this case I know the data right when I select it on `selectA` and it cannot be changed any other way, so I wonder if it's necessary to make a `useEffect` to observe that value rather than just grabbing it and setting it directly.

Keep in mind that the value of `selectA.potato` can be of any type, but I'm thinking of it being an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `useEffect` might be slower but I don't think performance is the main concern here.

In general the official advice is not to overuse `useEffect`. If you can do something without it, it is better probably to do it without it.

From the [docs](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect):

> Effects are an escape hatch from the React paradigm. They let you
> “step outside” of React and synchronize your components with some
> external system like a non-React widget, network, or the browser DOM.
> If there is no external system involved (for example, if you want to
> update a component’s state when some props or state change), you
> shouldn’t need an Effect. Removing unnecessary Effects will make your
> code easier to follow, faster to run, and less error-prone.

ps. The "Effect" in above quote refers to react specific definition. Not the broader programming concept of "side effect".

Comment: I see! Didn't read that specific part from the docs! So much clearer now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

About the performance, setting the value directly in `onChange` is better. With `useEffect` you do twice rerenders, since the second update will occur after the first rerender. **But in most cases that won't matter that much.**

`useEffect` is good if your `selectA` getting updated from more than 1 place. For example if you have CRUD operations on it, the update logic for `selectB` will be in 1 place, not on each operation.

In some cases you will be forced to update the second state in the `onChange`, if you want the UI to rerender with the both new values instead of 1 by 1