# React useMemo field change and initial undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a generic React component for Dropdown which kind of renders for multiple dynamic fields (based on server response)

```
const dropdownFld = watch(field.id); //Returns object {"text": "", "code": ""}

useMemo(() => {
    handleMyFieldChange(field.id, valueFrom(dropdownFld ));
}, [dropdownFld ]);
```

What I observe is that during the initial render, useMemo is trigerred with "dropdownFld" as undefined and then it runs again with the actual value from the server response (e.g. {"text": "My Option 1", "code": "MY_OPT_1"})

This causes "handleMyFieldChange" to be run twice and what I really want is that during the inital load, handleMyFieldChange should not really trigger and it should only trigger when the dropdown option is manually changed by the user say from "My Option 1" to "My Option 2"

Can I update the useMemo in the above code to somehow prevent this from happening? i.e. I do not want undefined to trigger change

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is to add them in `useEffect` and check whether the component has mounted or not.

Also, `useMemo` is used for performance optimization, while what you are using may work for your case, `useEffect` would still be a preferable way to satisfy your need.

What you can do is

```
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!mounted) {
            setMounted(true)
            return
        }
        handleMyFieldChange(field.id, valueFrom(dropdownFld))
    }, [dropdownFld])
```

So `handleMyFieldChange` wont be executed during the very initial rendering, while `handleMyFieldChange` will be fired properly every time `dropdownFld` is updated.

Comment: Thanks...is mounted to be added as a useState variable ?

Comment: Do you really need useEffect to do this?  Cannot OP just have a ternary that asks if `dropdownFld` is set?

Comment: @copenndthagen yeah sorry forgot to add that.

Comment: @Zak sure, as long as it satisfies the requirement, use whatever you see fit. This is based on his needs and how it would normally be done in React's way, especially that's what `useEffect` designed for.

Comment: See [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76286598/react-is-it-best-for-performance-to-use-useeffect-or-change-a-value-directly-w#:~:text=In%20general%20the%20official%20advice,to%20do%20it%20without%20it.) -- You should avoid useEffect if there is "another way of doing it" --  using `useEffect` causes overhead on the browser, and is generally considered "overused" in the React community.  And [Official Documentation](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)

Comment: @Zak agreed, however, in this case, `useEffect` is the right way, so `handleMyFieldChange` + the ternary logic isn't fired on every rerender, consequently improving the performance compared to the way you proposed.

Comment: @Taiwei Tuan : Just a basic question, why does control go inside useMemo initially with undefined value? Regarding useEffect, I had opted for useMemo for performance reason....though in this case, not sure if the mounted can be used with useMemo ?

Comment: @copenndthagen Assuming you have the Strict Mode enabled, Its the "Strict Mode" in react, which "can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic." and "is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions: Class component constructor , render , and shouldComponentUpdate methods." https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects